# gmail script only pull from first email of each thread

Tags: multithreading, google-sheets, gmail-api

I'm trying to parse extract data from g-mail messages using a script that uses regex. Got the rest of the main functions of the script working however there is one pretty big issue.

**The script is only returning data from the first message of each thread. I would like it to return the data from each message in each thread, Ive been playing around with it but so far no luck.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
function processInboxToSheet() {


var start = 0;
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
var SPREADSHEET_URL =    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QDg";
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';
var result = [];


var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

var content = messages[0].getRawContent();
```

Here's the second half of the script:

```
if (content) {
  var tmp;
  tmp = content.match(/\<\!\-\-\soutRadius\s\s\[*(.+?)\]/);

  var radius = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Unknown Radius';

  tmp = content.match(/\<\!\-\-\sX\s\s\[*(.+?)\]/);
  var longitude = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Unknown Latitude';

  tmp = content.match(/\<\!\-\-\sY\s\s\[*(.+?)\]/);
  var latitude = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Unknown Longitude';

  tmp = content.match(/\The mobile number was located on\s*(.+?)\s/);
  var date = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'Unknown date';

  tmp = content.match(/([\d:]*)\s*GMT/);
  var time = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'Unknown time';

  sheet.appendRow([date, time, longitude, latitude, radius]);

  Utilities.sleep(500);
}
  };
```

Comment: I figured it out... I had the components of the script but it was not properly put together I guess. Thanks for the help as you can probably tell I have very minimal experience with scripting. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just loop through the messages as well?

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var messages = threads[i];

  for(var j = 0; j < messages; j++) {
    var content = messages[j].getRawContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried looping through the messages, but its still getting data from only one email per thread. I wonder if I need to add a a method that returns all messages, have been looking through the google script reference but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a similar problem in my PHP API, for some reason I just get the first message. After a while in my GMAIL account I removed the label from my message and re-add and for my surprise the API was updated with the missing data.

After that every time I want to fetch a Thread i just force a update on the thread and I always receive the correct data don't know why but it's works.

Example of code I run before any select on mails :

```
public function updateThread($threadId, $labels){              
    $modify = new Google_Service_Gmail_ModifyThreadRequest;
    $modify->setAddLabelIds($labels);        
    return $this->service->users_threads->modify($this->userId, $threadId, $modify);
}
```